# ¿Cómo guardar el contenido de un listbox en Excel usando C#?

Tags: c#, excel

En esta aplicación se pide al usuario que ingrese una ruta de directorio y un término de búsqueda. Luego intenta leer todos los archivos de todos los directorios bajo esa ruta y si alguno de ellos contiene el texto de búsqueda, agrega la ruta a un `ListBox`.

Luego de esto y es lo que aun me falta es ¿como guardar en mi equipo el resultado de esa búsqueda en un archivo `excel`? este  generado automáticamente con mi aplicación.

Parte del código que ahora tengo en C# forms es:

```
   private void btnexplorador_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtruta.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    private void btnbuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbxlista.Items.Clear();
        string ruta = @"" + txtruta.Text; //Escribir ruta
        string texto = txtfiltro.Text; //Escribir texto a buscar

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(ruta, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        //List<string> encontrados = new List<string>();
        foreach (string item in files)
        {
            string contenido = File.ReadAllText(item);

            if (contenido.Contains(texto))

                lbxlista.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

Comment: Le sugiero este tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659643/Csharp-Query-Excel-and-CSV-Files-Using-LinqToExcel

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo generando un [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Separando cada valor con una comma(,). Cada comma(,) representa una columna y cada salto de linea representa(\n) representa una fila:

```
string directorios = String.Join("\n", lbxlista.Items.Select(x=>x.ToList()));
File.WriteAllText("c:/archivo_excel.csv", directorios);
```

Si abrimos el archivo nos lo mostraria asi:

```
--------
| item1 |
---------
--------
| item2 |
---------
--------
| item3 |
---------
```

Mientras que si reemplazamos el salto de linea(`\n`) por una comma(`,`), el resultado seria:

```
--------  ------  ------
| item3 | item2 | item3 |
--------  ------  ------
```