# Exportar datos a Excel desde vista MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Necesito saber como puedo exportar la siguiente tabla que tengo en una vista de mi proyecto a un documento de excel.

La tabla que deseo exportar a excel es la siguiente:

```
    <table class="exampletb table table-bordered table-hover display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Colaborador</th>
                <th>Lider</th>
                <th>Eje</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.colaboradores)
    {
        var namelider = item.lider;
        var codigo_col = item.codigo;
        var lider = (from p in ((List<SI_OldMutual.Models.Collaborators>)ViewBag.email_lider).Where(n => n.nombres == namelider)
                     select p.email).ToList();
        if (lider.Count == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.test = "No existe";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.test = lider[0];
        }
        <tr>
            <td>@item.nombres</td>
            <td>@item.lider</td>
            <td>@item.eje_funcional</td>
            @foreach (var peso in ((List<SI_OldMutual.Models.Objectives>)ViewBag.pesos).Where(n => n.Lider == ViewBag.test))
            {
                <td>@peso.Peso_Objetivo</td>
            }
            @foreach (var calificacion in ((List<SI_OldMutual.Models.CalificarColaborador>)ViewBag.calificaciones).Where(n => n.codigo_colaborador == codigo_col))
        {
                <td>@calificacion.calificacion</td>
            }

        </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Me dicen que lo puedo hacer desde el controlador pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo, soy nuevo en esto del Asp.Net Mvc5. Mi idea es hacer que exporte esa tabla con la misma lógica que estoy usando en vista.

Mi controlador es este:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.colaboradores = (from p in db.Collaborators
                         where p.grupo_lider == "NO"
                         select p).ToList();

            ViewBag.pesos = (from p in db.Objectives
                         select p).ToList();

            ViewBag.calificaciones = (from p in db.CalificarColaboradors
                        select p).ToList();

            ViewBag.email_lider = (from p in db.Collaborators where p.grupo_lider == "SI"
                               select p).ToList();

            return View();
        }
```

Cabe aclarar que la tabla se me pinta en la vista de la siguiente manera puesto que los resultados de los pesos y calificaciones pueden variar según la persona y no siempre son la misma cantidad, dejo una imagen para que se entienda un poco mejor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por esto es que necesito poder exportar esta tabla así tal cual como se me pinta en la vista o al menos utilizando la misma lógica.

Por si las dudas mi `namespace` es `SI_OldMutual`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta respuesta esta [basada en una respuesta anterior a una pregunta parecida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/86780/38468):

Puedes hacerlo generando un CSV que es soportado por Microsoft Excel. La coma(`,`) representa una columna(hay casos en donde un punto y coma(`;`) es lo que representa una columna pero no puedo decir con exactitud en cuales circunstancias se da este comportamiento) y el salto de linea(`\n`) representa una nueva fila.

Si fueramos a generar la siguiente tabla:

```html
  <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Header1</th>
         <th>Header1</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Dato</td>
          <td>Dato</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dato</td>
          <td>Dato Dato</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Para guardarlo como CSV seria:

```
var datos = "Header1,Header2 \n Dato,Dato\n Dato, Dato Dato";
```

Este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice una pequeña adaptacion de tu codigo a como se generaria desde un `ActionResult`. Quizas tengas que hacerle algunas modificaciones pero ya tienes la idea de como generarlo:

```
public ActionResult GenerarExcel()
{
var colaboradores = (from p in db.Collaborators 
                    where p.grupo_lider == "NO" 
                    select p).ToList(); 
var pesos = (from p in db.Objectives 
            select p).ToList(); 

var calificaciones = (from p in db.CalificarColaboradors 
                        select p).ToList(); 

var email_lider = (from p in db.Collaborators 
select p).ToList(); 


StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 

//Agregamos las cabezeras 
builder.Append("Colaborador").Append(";") 
.Append("Lider").Append(";") 
.Append("Eje"); 
builder.Append("\n"); 

foreach (var item in colaboradores) 
{ 

    var namelider = item.lider; 
    var codigo_col = item.codigo; 
    var lider = (from p in email_lider.Where(n => n.nombres == namelider) 
    select p.email).ToList(); 

    var nombreLider = string.Empty; 

    if (lider.Count == 0) 
    { 
        nombreLider = "No existe"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        nombreLider = lider[0]; 
    } 

    builder.Append(item.nombres).Append(";") 
    .Append(item.lider).Append(";") 
    .Append(item.eje_funcional).Append(";"); 

    foreach (var peso in pesos.Where(n => n.Lider == nombreLider)) 
    { 
        builder.Append(peso.Peso_Objetivo).Append(";"); 
    } 

    foreach (var calificacion in calificaciones.Where(n => n.codigo_colaborador == codigo_col)) 
    { 
        builder.Append(calificacion.calificacion).Append(";"); 
    } 

    builder.Append("\n");// agregamos una nueva fila 
} 


// Lo encodeamos con UTF8 para mostrar los acentos correctamente.
var excelBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());
var excelConUT8Encoding = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(excelBytes).ToArray();

// guardamos el contenido del archivo en la ruta especificada
var rutaExcel = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/excel.csv"); 
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(rutaExcel, excelConUT8Encoding); 

return File(rutaExcel, "text/csv", "Calificaciones.csv"); 
 }
```

**Actualizacion:**

Se le agrego el soporte para el encoding de UTF8 para que muestre los acentos.

Comment: Hola compañero Einer, muy bueno tu ejemplo sin embargo me dice que Append no existe en el contexto actual, ya probe con control . y no me arroja para importar algun using

Comment: Pudiste importar la clase `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Verifica que no sea `append` sino `Append`. Editando la pregunta edite algunas palabras sin querer.

Comment: aqui te dejo una imagen del error https://image.ibb.co/kHZKja/image.png

Comment: Lo solucione removiendo los (;) sin embargo tengo un error en File.WriteAllText(ruta, builder.ToString());

Comment: Elimina los  2 primeros puntos y coma `;`. Fijate que en la respuesta no los tiene.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62355/discussion-between-einer-and-bygroxd).

Answer (score 2):

Yo tuve exactamente el mismo problema y te muestro como lo resolvi. Hay que usar una libreria Javascript que te dejo al final.

1-Creas un boton y le asignas una funcion, digamos "onclick='GenerarExcel()'"

2-Luego en la funcion Generar Excel escribes lo siguiente:

```
function GenerarExcel(){

      $('#NombreDeTuTabla').table2excel({ name: "Prueba", filename: "NombreDelArchivo"});

}
```

Y listo!!

Aca te dejo el demo descargable

http://www.jqueryscript.net/download/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.zip

lo que tienes que hacer es un include en el header de tu pagina del archivo **jquery.table2excel.js**, que se encuentra en la carpeta **src**

Acordate de ponerle un ID a tu tabla!!

Espero que te sea util

Comment: La ventaja que tiene mi código es que no tenes limitación de exportación de datos, algo que me sucedía cuando lo hacia mediante otro método (en javascript): Antes tenia un limite de exportación de 300 registros, luego pinchaba.